# In Where-Object what can i use to search DIsplayName in S4B?

Tags: powershell-2.0, skype-for-business

I've been searching for a solution to my issue but haven't found one that fit yet.  I've been asked by one of our infrastructure team members to provide all the conference room phone numbers and display names in a specific office.

I can pull up all the numbers of the office using -

```
Get-CsUser |Where-Object {$_.LineURI -Like "*area code*prefix*"} |Export-csv "filepath".
```

I found a different question here that taught me to use -and for multiple search items.

So I modified my search to be -

```
Get-CsUser |Where-Object {($_.LineURI -Like "*AC*Prefix*") -and ($_.DisplayName -contains "Conference")} |Export-csv "filepath"
```

But now i get a blank CSV file.  I've found that using $_.DisplayName doesn't return any results.  I've also tried Identity in place of DisplayName and got a blank csv file.

What can i use in place of DisplayName to fine tune the results to just the Conference Room phones?

Here's the Get-CsUser result on a conference room as an example.

```
    Identity                    : CN=Conference Room - (HLY) Phoenix,OU=Services,DC=mydomain,DC=com
    VoicePolicy                 : NA-US-International
    VoiceRoutingPolicy          : 
    ConferencingPolicy          : 
    PresencePolicy              : 
    DialPlan                    : 
    LocationPolicy              : 
    ClientPolicy                : 
    ClientVersionPolicy         : 
    ArchivingPolicy             : 
    ExchangeArchivingPolicy     : Uninitialized
    PinPolicy                   : 
    ExternalAccessPolicy        : 
    MobilityPolicy              : 
    PersistentChatPolicy        : 
    UserServicesPolicy          : 
    CallViaWorkPolicy           : 
    ThirdPartyVideoSystemPolicy : 
    HostedVoiceMail             : True
    HostedVoicemailPolicy       : NA-10-Digit
    HostingProvider             : SRV:
    RegistrarPool               : XXX-S4B-FE-01.mydomain.com
    Enabled                     : True
    SipAddress                  : sip:phoenix@mydomain.com
    LineURI                     : tel:+1xxxxxxxxxx
    EnterpriseVoiceEnabled      : True
    ExUmEnabled                 : False
    HomeServer                  : CN=Lc Services,CN=Microsoft,CN=2:1,CN=Pools,CN=RTC Service,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=mydomain,DC=com
    DisplayName                 : Conference Room - (HLY) Phoenix
    SamAccountName              : phoenix
```

Answer (score 1):

Found my mistake.  I didn't have a wildcard before and after "Conference" -

```
Get-CsUser |Where-Object {($_.LineURI -Like "*AC*Prefix*") -and ($_.DisplayName -contains "*Conference*")} |Export-csv "filepath"
```